# Cannot fetch user using redux from an api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

Having trouble fetching data from an api with redux. I am working with React frontend and express backend. I'm trying to set up authentication through Google OAuth on the backend and then send headers(which are set successfully) back to my React client. I can fetch some data successfully from an api, but cannot fetch user using redux.

My action creator for fetching the user:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await posts.get ('/api/current_user');
  dispatch ({type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data});
};
```

In the above code, posts is just an export which allows me to make requests using axios to the api

Route handler to send the user data to the client:

```
  app.get ('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
    console.log("this is a req user", req.user)
    res.send (req.user);
  });
```

note that console.log on the route handler successfully logs the user which I am trying to fetch.

On the client side, I think I have connected the redux store properly to this component:

```
  render () {
  console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        <div>

          {/* {this.renderAuthButton ()} */}
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {auth: state.auth};
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps)(GoogleAuth);
```

When I try to log this.props it does not appear log the user at all. I've tried calling the fetchUser function within the render method but it does not return the user either. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated and I would love to provide any additional information. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you map also your action creators (your `fetchUser`) to your component with `mapDispatchToProps`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect dispatch to redux like this:

```
import { fetchUser } from '....'
//
//
//
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {auth: state.auth};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {fetchUser: () => fetchUser(dispatch)};
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GoogleAuth);
```

Call action in life cycle of Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.fetchUser()
}
render () {
   console.log(this.props) // Here you will see data that return from 
   // fetchUser action in store redux at the second time of render Component
   return (
       ...
   )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've tried doing that and I get dispatch is not a function. Perhaps it's because I'm using redux thunk and async function in my action creators. I've tried calling fetchUser in the life cycle of Component and there was only one console.log. I believe if everything went as it should, I would see 2 logs, since as soon as the async fetchUser function fetches the data the store should update and re-render the component?  I've also added a console.log inside the fetch_user reducer and it seems to get the correct action.type but still no data

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of mapping action creators with using of redux-thunk should be this:

```js
import { fetchUser } from '....'
// ...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {auth: state.auth};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {fetchUser: () => dispatch(fetchUser())};
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GoogleAuth);
```

or simply send your action creators as mapped object to the second parameter of connect:

```js
import { fetchUser } from '....'
// ...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {auth: state.auth};
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, {fetchUser})(GoogleAuth);
```

Read more in [this part of react-redux documenation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops).

Comment: I've tried doing that, but I get dispatch is not a function error. Any ideas why I might be getting this error? I've also tried to send my action creator as mapped object to the the second parameter of connect and call it in the life cycle of Component which works fine but still does not fetch the user properly, it simply returns an empty string. When I go to the api address directly the user displays properly as an object.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting 'dispatch is not a function error'? In map dispatch to props or in your action creator? Do you have wrapped your application with react-redux Provider? Try to post code of your store initialization, to check if you have redux-thunk correctly applied.

Comment: I see my mistake now, I just copied the code example from another answer, the mapDispatchToProps should return  `{fetchUser: () => dispatch(fetchUser())};` instead of `{fetchUser: dispatch(fetchUser())};`. I fixed it in my answer.